# Why can't TestCafe expect a expression including both a Selector and a const value?

Tags: javascript, testcafe

I have a JS code of TestCafe which could not get the expected result (NaN)

```js
await t.expect(Selector('some-expression').count - someConstVar).eql(1)
```

However if changed to following, it would work well.

```js
await t.expect(Selector('some-expression').count).eql(1 + someConstVar)
```

I felt the first one questionable and changed it to the second, although it worked, but just curious, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Selector('some-expression').count` expression returns a `Promise` object, not a number. This is required for correct work of [the built-in wait mechanism](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402827/guides/advanced-guides/built-in-wait-mechanisms). Refer the following help topic to learn more about how Selector API works: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402829/guides/basic-guides/element-selectors#how-selectors-work.

Comment: Great, clear. `expect` should also take a `Promise`